# Fatal exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating FCM in my android application, for that I am inserting firebase dependency such as  **compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'** and **compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'** in **build.gradle** file.
However, when I sync the gradle with the changes, it build successfully. But when I run this application, it shows error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   isDeviceProtectedStorage(Landroid/content/Context;)Z in class
>   Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same version for Firebase or Google Play Service (in your case firebase-core and firebase-messaging) should solve the issue. Avoid using libraries with different versions.

Moreover, [isDeviceProtectedStorage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#isDeviceProtectedStorage(android.content.Context)) was added on version 24.1.0 check if you are using this version (or higher).

Comment: I have changed version as same for firebase dependencies, and also changed API Version greater than 24, but still shows same error.

Comment: and what about contextCompact? do you have this version or higher? com.android.support:support-compat: version 24.1.0